# React Component not rending in Play app

Tags: javascript, scala, reactjs, playframework, react-bootstrap

I have a Play/scala/sbt project with following React component saved at `app/assets/javascripts/nav.jsx`:

```
class Nav extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="@routes.MainViewController.index" id="logo">@Messages("application.banner")</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="@routes.MainViewController.index">@Messages("application.home")</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@routes.MainViewController.about">@Messages("application.about")</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Nav />,
    document.getElementById('nav')
);
```

In my `main.scala.html` file:

```
@(title: String)(body: Html)(webJarAssets: WebJarAssets)(implicit messages: Messages)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        @* Here's where we render the page title `String`. *@
        <title>@title</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <script src="@routes.MainJsonController.javascriptRoutes" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("css/bootstrap.min.css"))'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"))'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("css/font-awesome.min.css"))'>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("jquery.min.js"))'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("js/bootstrap.min.js"))'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("react.js"))'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("react-bootstrap.min.js"))'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("react-dom.js"))'></script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="container">

            <div id="nav"></div>

                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                        @body
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, my navigation bar does not appear. I was expecting for the Component to render at `<div id="nav"></div>`. What could I be doing wrong?

**Asset route**

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

I feel like I need to include the component as a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@routes.Assets.versioned("/javascripts/nav.jsx")'></script>
```

This renders the whole page with no compilation errors but the Component still doesn't appear.

I was getting an **exception** at line 7, where the first `<nav>` tag starts.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

When I **corrected** the include to `<script type="text/javascript" src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/nav.js")'></script>` and placed it just below my closing `</body>` tag, I now get this:

```
Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
    at invariant (react.js:18354)
    at Object._registerComponent (react.js:11047)
    at Object._renderNewRootComponent (react.js:11070)
    at Object.wrapper [as _renderNewRootComponent] (react.js:12353)
    at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (react.js:11150)
    at Object.render (react.js:11170)
    at Object.wrapper [as render] (react.js:12353)
    at nav.js:25
```

Comment: I don't think that play will compile your react components or something similar. I do not now react but the scripts on the `assets` folder you have to link them on the templates in order to use.

Comment: Have a look here it may give you a more concrete help: [link](http://matthiasnehlsen.com/blog/2014/01/05/play-framework-and-facebooks-react-library/)

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes:

- Inserted a forward slash at the beginning of the path, i.e. `/javascripts` instead of `javascripts`
- Replaced `.jsx` with `.js`
- Put my script at the bottom of the .scala template, right before my closing body tag, instead of within my `<head>`

Result:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@routes.Assets.versioned("/javascripts/nav.js")'></script>
```

Finally, my navigation bar rendered correctly.